# Where can I find a list of the various rails versions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, version

I'm having an issue with rails 3.0.7 that led me to this subquestion:

Where can I find the list of rails version for 3.0, e.g. 3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.11,. etc. ?

I've googled and looked at wikipedia and SO and a variey of the main ruby sites but can't find this 'list of versions' info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see all published gems at rubygems.org:

http://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions

You can also have a look at branches and tags on github:

https://github.com/rails/rails

Answer (score 13):

`$ gem list -r --all rails`

`rails (3.2.2, 3.2.1, 3.2.0, 3.1.4, 3.1.3, 3.1.2, 3.1.1, 3.1.0, 3.0.12, 3.0.11, 3.0.10, 3.0.9, 3.0.8, 3.0.7, 3.0.6, 3.0.5, 3.0.4, 3.0.3, 3.0.2, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 2.3.14, 2.3.12, 2.3.11, 2.3.10, 2.3.9, 2.3.8, 2.3.7, 2.3.6, 2.3.5, 2.3.4, 2.3.3, 2.3.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.2, 2.1.2, 2.1.1, 2.1.0, 2.0.5, 2.0.4, 2.0.2, 2.0.1, 2.0.0, 1.2.6, 1.2.5, 1.2.4, 1.2.3, 1.2.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.0, 1.1.6, 1.1.5, 1.1.4, 1.1.3, 1.1.2, 1.1.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.0, 0.14.4, 0.14.3, 0.14.2, 0.14.1, 0.13.1, 0.13.0, 0.12.1, 0.12.0, 0.11.1, 0.11.0, 0.10.1, 0.10.0, 0.9.5, 0.9.4.1, 0.9.4, 0.9.3, 0.9.2, 0.9.1, 0.9.0, 0.8.5, 0.8.0)`

Answer (score 1):

You can find it on rubygems.org, see [all versions of rails](http://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions)

Answer (score 0):

You can find all rails via github tags:

https://github.com/rails/rails/tags